# UIPopoverController not relocating when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8, xcode6

I have run into an bug associated with UIPopoverController relocation in iOS 8.

In iOS 7 i was using the following approach to relocate the popover if the keyboard has squashed the popover too much, and top was a better place for it to be placed (The popover contains a UITableView):

In the UIViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(p_keyboardHasChangedFrame:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

And the method

```
- (void)p_keyboardHasChangedFrame:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    if (self.pPopoverVC){
        [self.pPopoverVC presentPopoverFromRect:self.pSmallView.frame
                                         inView:self.view
                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                                       animated:NO];
    }
}
```

But for some weird reason it does not work in iOS 8

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @Marg? I'm having the same problem. It seems Apple want the popover to be dismissed before presenting it again, but if it's dismissed the first responder resigns so the keyboard is dismissed as well!  I've tried seeing if UIPopoverPresentationController helps, but didn't seem to offer anything different...